# deep data is not implemented FFmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I have a question about FFmpeg when I'm trying to convert Deep Compositing "EXR" files sequence to "MOV" video file , I've got this :

[exr @ 00000294dd99f100] deep data is not implemented. Update your FFmpeg version to the newest one from Git. If the problem still occurs, it means that your file has a feature which has not been implemented.

[exr @ 00000294dd99f100] deep data is not implemented. Update your FFmpeg version to the newest one from Git. If the problem still occurs, it means that your file has a feature which has not been implemented.

[image2 @ 00000294dd99d1c0] decoding for stream 0 failed

[image2 @ 00000294dd99d1c0] Could not find codec parameters for stream 0

(Video: exr, none): unspecified size
Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' and 'probesize' options.

Any help please :)

Comment: I believe the error is pretty self explanatory. Did you upgrade to the latest ffmpeg from git?

Comment: I'm using the latest update 4.2.2 for windows